# How to use Razor to create an HTML file at build time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, razor

In a VS2010 web app project, I'd like to define a Razor template which is transformed into a separate concrete .html file at build time.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Comment: You could host it local, and use a tool like http://www.spadixbd.com/backstreet/ to download the pages local.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the scenario? What do you expect the Razor file to look like and what kind of output do you want? How do you expect to provide model data into the file?

Comment: Sure, I want to create a static Error.html page which will be referenced by <customErrors> in web.config. There's no data as such but I want to use some sort of template because the static links within the page (css, etc) differ depending on the solution configuration. I've since used a T4 template which checks the active configuration and writes out the relevant links, but I thought Razor might be more suited as it is markup that I'm trying to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to build an external tool (exe, powershell script) that creates the file, and add it as a build action.

I recently blogged about creating a PowerShell module ([blogpost here](http://blog.dantup.com/2011/04/formatting-powershell-objects-using-the-razor-engine), [source code here](http://code.dantup.com/psrazor)) that might be useful. You can just pipe some objects into the Cmdlet, like this:

```
Get-Command | Format-Razor "Command: @Model.Name, @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { @i }"
```

If you're not familiar with PowerShell, you could do something similar with some C# and a compile console app. Some info on this can be found on [Andrew Nurse's blog](http://www.vibrantcode.com/blog/2010/11/16/hosting-razor-outside-of-aspnet-revised-for-mvc3-rc.html), though his post only goes as far as creating the code. You could convert my PowerShell back to C#, or copy Andrew Nurses code from [this presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT50) (right near the end) that does the compilation (my PowerShell was written based on the contents of this webcast :))